# What to do about my will (post-death wishes) while working abroad?

Tags: usa

I shall soon be moving from the UK to the USA for work for ~3 years.

I have a will in the UK, lodged with family members here (there's no requirement for it to be with a lawyer here).

What, if anything, should I do to make sure that things would go smoothly if I were to die while in the US?

Comment: Couldn't find any obviously appropriate tags here, beyond the country one.

Comment: I think this question would be better asked on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The Law stack is a better fit, but foreign wills are generally admissible in U.S. jurisdictions. You may, however, want to modify/update it should your US employment include death benefits (some do), and should others things change, e.g., you acquire real property, heirs, or liabilities in the US.

Comment: Note that "will" and "post-death wishes" aren't the same thing.  For instance, by the time your will is located and found to contain "bury me …", you might have already been cremated.  The wishes should be kept much more readily available, and it doesn't hurt to have one with you and several copies in different locations, so long as they are dated and identical.